# How Can I Return Search Result Suggestions Instantly In PHP or JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a webpage I am working on, where I'd like to have a text/search box that a user can type into and get search suggestions instantly.

For example, if the user types in "San" they might get a list to choose from that looks something like this:

```
San Francisco
San Bernardino
San Diego
```

etc.

Can somebody please point me in the right direction as to how to do this quickly and effectively?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Where would the suggestions be coming from? A JavaScript object already in the page, or from a live search of your database using ajax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of Javascript autocomplete solutions out there, here's jQuery UI's version: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: This is actually exactly what I need. But how can I get the list to populate from an Oracle 10G database? Before I used to have a list popluated from the database, but it was too long and I opted for this.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation for the "source" option: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source  You can specify various methods of populating the list, from a standard Javascript array, to a URL that returns the list in JSON for a given search query (most likely what you need).  As you've tagged this question PHP, you'll probably want to write a script that queries your database to provide the suggestions and returns them in JSON.

Comment: Actually, it's not really from a URL. I loaded the data onto a PHP array. I'm just curious as to how to get the PHP array to load in that JavaScript function you provided.

Comment: You could get your Javascript to make an AJAX request to a URL that returns a JSON encoded version of your PHP array, or you can JSON encode your PHP array and output it directly to your page in a Javascript variable: Either approach would work.

Comment: If anyone can see this, this was the answer: `var availableTags = <?php echo json_encode($dbArray); ?>;`, just replace the array from the sample code in the link with something similar to this.